# Data structure for page layout like CSS floats

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, layout, data-structures

Suppose I have my own markup language that allows me to consume an array of TextElements and ImageElements.  Each of these can have properties like "float: left/right/none" and "clear: none/left/right/both".  Additionally, non-floated elements can flow around floated elements.  Basically, all like CSS float layout.

For example:

Elem1  Elem2
Elem3
Elem4 Elem5 **_*Elem6***

What's the best data structure to use to store these elements while I'm laying them out?  I need something which makes it easy to answer questions like:

- Is there enough space to fit Element2 left or right of Element1?
- What's the page coordinates of Element1, origin and size?

I'll basically store a structure like:

{ Element, Origin(x, y), Size(w, h) }

for each already-laid-out element in this data structure.

There are things like RTrees, QuadTrees and such, but I want something simple to abstractly represent the layout of rectangles on a page for use in my layout algorithm.

NOTE: I am not doing this in HTML, it is for layout of elements in an iOS App, and I cannot use iOS 6 constraints since I need to support earlier iOS versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a binary heap could be made to work for what you want. [Wikipedia explains binary heaps quite well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

The binary heap has two properties that make it nice for what you want:

1. It is a complete tree, which resembles structurally a laid-out page of elements.
2. The nodes are ordered such that each node is greater (or less, depending on which you want) than its children. In your case, "greater" means "placed further left and towards the top".

You have a list of elements that, in the absence of floats, would be laid out sequentially, wrapping lines as necessary. Thus, building a heap in the absence of floats would simply add nodes to the tree in the order they are received.

Floats complicate this, because they are placed higher than the nodes that preceded them (or lower than those that follow them in the case of right floats). Fortunately, building a heap allows for this by bubbling new nodes up to their proper place. So, as long as you can define a function that orders a floated element with respect to its peers, this can work.

It's that *if* that I'm not sure about, and unfortunately, I don't have enough time right now to explore the idea more completely.

Anyway, presuming you have a correct heap, repeatedly removing the topmost element should enumerate the nodes in the order they should be placed on the page.

I think [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) has a binary heap, but I can't verify that since the server where the documentation is kept seems to be offline at the time of posting.

Good luck and I hope this is helpful.